# Word to describe being grateful in an understated way?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a letter asking for feedback from someone who is an expert on the topic. I would like to indicate that I am grateful for their input, and possibly how useful it is for me so as to praise them, but I don't want to give the impression that I am begging them to do something or that they would be making a huge sacrifice or to otherwise use hyperbole. Here are some phrases that I thought about and rejected:

> - I would be honored/privileged/blessed
>     (too over the top, begging/groveling)
> - It would benefit me enormously
>   (too selfish, I want to indicate that their input is valuable not how much I get from it)
> - I would love
>   (somewhat better but doesn't really praise the expert or indicate how valuable the input is)

Is there a good word that fits my (vague) criteria?

edit: I would like to put the expert in the mindset that they would be demonstrating their expertise (which they might be more inclined to do), rather than just doing me a huge favor (which they might be less inclined to do).

Comment: Why not simply say "I would be very grateful", or "I would be in your debt"?

Comment: "grateful" sounds too much like they are mostly doing me a favor (and what's in it for them)? see my edit also

Comment: Vocabulary aside, I think you're going too far out of your way to avoid casting this as a favor.  Many people actually enjoy doing favors, even for their enemies.  See "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Franklin_effect".

Comment: As advice, in your request, demonstrate that you have done your research, and convince the expert that your interests are strongly aligned with their own. Most people would respond favorably to a request for help under those circumstances. The benefit to them would be a connection with someone who appreciates their work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ***appreciate***:

> I would *appreciate* your feedback.

It shows that you desire feedback and would be grateful for it.

Comment: Agreed.  One often sees the phrase "any [help, expertise, etc.] you can provide would be appreciated", or something similar, in such correspondence.

Comment: "Appreciate" sounds too much like they are mostly doing me a favor (and what's in it for them)? see my edit also

Comment: Are you sure they wouldn't just see through your Jedi-mind-trick? I think most people react positively to someone who is honest about needing help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could say:

> I could use your feedback.

There's no thanking or begging.

Personally, I would go with jxh's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**value** (*transitive verb*):

to consider something important

> '*I've always valued her advice.*'

Source: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org)